# Unreachable If Statements with Remove Function for Singly Linked Lists

Tags: java

I am trying to create my own singly linked list in Java and am running into trouble when writing my remove function (which will take the desired node out of the list). 'hasNext' is a boolean that returns true if there is a node after something. The error I'm getting is that the if statements I have are unreachable. Any idea how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Please, indent your code correctly (and add the missing curly braces). An instruction after a `return` statement can't possibly be executed, since the method has returned. Hence the error.

Comment: Surround all your if and else blocks in curly braces to avoid confusion created by false indentations.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the tags in your profile, you are used to Python, where indentation marks the scope of branching instructions. That's not how most other programming languages, including Java, work, though.

Comment: *"hasNext' is a boolean that returns true if there is a node after something."* A boolean variable doesn't *return* anything; it *is* either true or false, and it's your responsibility to make sure it has the right value. In this code you have a method named `hasNext()` which *does* return the boolean value you want, so it's not clear why there is also a variable with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    if (hasNext == false) // If you're removing the final value
```

to

```
    if (hasNext() == false) // If you're removing the final value
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have no code that sets hasNext to false you can't get into that if block.